# Kill database connection is not supported when trying to import bacpac file to local SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to import a bacpac file that I got from Azure SQL database to SQL Server. I tried to use SSMS "import data-tier application and it gave me:

> Updating database
> *** Error importing database:Could not import package. Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 4630, Level 16, State 1,
> Line 1 The permission 'KILL DATABASE CONNECTION' is not supported in
> this version of SQL Server. Alternatively, use the server level 'ALTER
> ANY CONNECTION' permission. Error SQL72045: Script execution error.
> The executed script: GRANT KILL DATABASE CONNECTION TO
> [test_db];

I also tried to use the `SQLPackage.exe` from windows but it gives me the exact same error in the command line.  I did not find much help googling the error code or description.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import .bacpac file of azure SQL database into my on-premises/local SQL server by following below procedure:
right click on database and select import Data-tier Application.

[image]

Got introduction page click on next in import settings page browse for .bacpac file from local. If it is in azure storage we can browse it from there also.

[image]

specify the name for database:

[image]

click on next will get summary page:

[image]

Click on next it executes the import operation.

[image]

database is imported successfully.

[image]

In my case I didn't get any error I am using SSMS latest version.
According to your error you need to enable **contained database authentication** on your on-premises SQL Server. It's always enabled in Azure SQL Database by using you can use below code to enable:

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

You can check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185832/grant-permission-to-kill-connections-sessions-for-certain-databases-only) similar question, it may work.